# Ajax and Json in cakephp 3.x

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

struggling hard to get response from controller on changing value of drop down but getting internal server error

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //alert( "ready!" );
    $('#devices-types-id').on('change', function() {
        alert( this.value ); 

         $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'FeaturesLists','action'=>'ajax_get_parent', '_ext' => 'json'));?>",
                dataType: 'text',
                async:false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

    });
```

but getting error with path first

`POST http://localhost/compare_devices/features-lists/%3C?php%20echo%20Router::ur…ction%27=%3E%27ajax_get_parent%27,%20%27_ext%27%20=%3E%20%27json%27));?%3E 404 (Not Found)`

if i write path in ajax call like this url: "/ajax_get_parent" then it does not give path error but "Internal server error"

```
POST http://localhost/compare_devices/features-lists/ajax_get_parent 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Controller code

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
     $this->Auth->allow(['ajaxGetParent']);
}
public function ajaxGetParent() {
    $this->layout = false;
     $this->set('text', 'SUCCESS');
    $this->set('_serialize', ['text']);
}
```

In routes.php i put this line

```
Router::extensions('json', 'xml');
```

i'm trying to get result in json but unable. Can you just guide me how i can do this. Many questions are already posted with same topic on 'SO' but most of them are for Cakephp 2.x and i tried some different solutions(help from SO and google) but could n't solve it. can you guide me how i can get response in json and resolve path problem.

Comment: Where you put your jQuery script?

Comment: using jquery online                                                                                   echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'); 
        echo $this->Html->script('featureList.js');                                            rest of the code in separate file named 'featureList.js' and then include it in view file

Comment: you are including a .js file, so you can't put php file in it as it will not be parsed. That's why you are getting the 404 error. About the 500 error you have to take a look at the logs to see what's happening.  Did you load RequestHandler component?

Comment: this view file having .js file included is different while the response view (controller funuction) is different

Comment: actually i was trying to get response without creating view file for that action. now it's working. but in response full html data is given back. how can i get only set data. @arilia

Answer (score 1):

Try making extensions an array:

```
Router::extensions(['json', 'xml']);
```

Here's an ajax call that works for me:

```
// ajax jquery testing
function doAjaxTest() {
    $.ajax({
        async:false,
        url: '/requests/get-order-info/123123/2121.json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

controller function is:

```
$response['result'] = "success";
$response['has_info'] = false;

$this->set(compact('response'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['response']);
```

You could also try to access the required URL in the browser directly. Also check the logs for the exact server error. Use dashes instead of underscores in URL.

Answer (score 1):

If is your jQuery code on same page **Change action name:**

```
url: "<?php echo Router::url(
  array(
    'controller'=>'FeaturesLists',
    'action'=>'ajaxGetParent',  // <--------
    '_ext' => 'json'
  ));?>",
```

**if is your jQuery code in external .js file:**

```
url: $('#devices-types-id').data('ajax-url);
```

**and in your view add:**

```
$this->Form->input('device_type_id',
  ['data-ajax-url' => $this->Url->build([
    'controller'=>'FeaturesLists',
    'action'=>'ajaxGetParent', 
    '_ext' => 'json'])
]);
```

**In Router:**

```
Router::extensions(['json']);
```

**Controller method**

```
public function ajaxGetParent() {
     //remove or comment this line, cakephp by default use ajax.ctp layout.
     #$this->layout = false;

     $this->set('text', 'SUCCESS');
    $this->set('_serialize', ['text']);
}
```

> if i write path in ajax call like this url: "/ajax_get_parent" then it does not give path error but "Internal server error"

**Try:**

```
POST http://localhost/compare_devices/features-lists/ajax-get-parent.json
```

Answer (score 0):

set '**_full**' paramater to **true**.

```
url: "<?php echo Router::url(
        array(
           'controller'=>'FeaturesLists',
           'action'=>'ajax_get_parent',
           '_ext' => 'json',
           '_full' => true //for full url path
     ));?>",
```

Comment: getting POST http://localhost/compare_devices/features-lists/ajax_get_parent 500 (Internal Server Error)